# How to find the bounds of a reverse double integration?

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus

> Evaluate the integral by reversing the order of integration:
>   $$\Large \int^{64}_0 \int^4_{\sqrt[3]{y}} 2e^{x^4} dx\ dy$$

I am trying to find the bounds for the questions above but I am not getting it right. The bounds I got are $4 \leq x \leq y^3$ and $0 \leq x \leq y^3$. If you guys can help me out on this problem I'd appreciate it a lot! Thanks!

Comment: Draw a picture to figure out what is your domain of integration. Draw all curves (just one is not constant) and look for common area.

Answer (score 1):

$$\int_0^{64} \int_{\sqrt[3]{y}}^42e^{x^4}\operatorname{d}x\operatorname{d}y=
\int_0^{64} \int_0^4 1_{[\sqrt[3]{y},+\infty)}(x)2e^{x^4}\operatorname{d}x\operatorname{d}y=(*).$$
Now, if $x,y\ge0 $ then $x\in[\sqrt[3]{y},+\infty)$ iff $\sqrt[3]{y}\le x$ iff $y\le x^3$.

So if $x,y\ge0$ then $1_{[\sqrt[3]{y},+\infty)}(x)=1_{[0,x^3]}(y)$.

Being in the square $[0,4]\times[0,64]$, then, in particular, we have $x,y\ge0$ and so

$$(*)=\int_0^{64} \int_0^4 1_{[0,x^3]}(y)2e^{x^4}\operatorname{d}x\operatorname{d}y=(**).$$

Now, since the integrand is non-negative, we can use [Tonelli's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fubini%27s_theorem#Tonelli's_theorem_for_non-negative_measurable_function) to switch the order of integrations, obtaining:
$$(**)=\int_0^4 \int_0^{64} 1_{[0,x^3]}(y)2e^{x^4}\operatorname{d}y\operatorname{d}x = \int_0^4 \int_0^{\min(64,x^3)} 2e^{x^4}\operatorname{d}y\operatorname{d}x = \int_0^4 \int_0^{x^3} 2e^{x^4}\operatorname{d}y\operatorname{d}x
\\ = \int_0^4 2e^{x^4} \int_0^{x^3} \operatorname{d}y\operatorname{d}x = \int_0^4 2e^{x^4} x^3\operatorname{d}x = \frac{1}{2} \int_0^4 \frac{\operatorname{d}}{\operatorname{d}x}\left(e^{x^4}\right) \operatorname{d}x = \frac{e^{256}-1}{2}.$$

Answer (score 0):

You've listed two sets of bounds for x. What you should have is a set of bounds for y (inner integral) and a set of bounds for x (outer integral) since you are reversing the order of integration to $\int \int f(x,y)\ dy\ dx$

Your outer bounds should not be dependent on y since you would have already integrated over y.

Draw a picture of the area enclosed by the original bounds and it will be easier to see what your new bounds should be.